# How to manage MySQL users in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

In Chef, how do you manage MySQL users? How would you set different privileges and passwords based on different environments? Would you use data bags or is there any other way to manage these?

We have a Chef repo for dev and a separate repo for prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Chef, how do you manage MySQL users?

In order to manage mysql users you can use `mysql_database_user` resource or `mysql_database` with action `query` when some things are not covered by `mysql_database_user resource`.

### manage user with mysql_database_user resource

```
mysql_database_user 'app-user' do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  password data_bag_item['password']
  host 'localhost'
  privileges [:all]
  action [:create, :grant]
end
```

where `data_bag_item['password']` is password stored in specific data bag.

### manage user with mysql_database resource

```
mysql_database 'create slave user' do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  sql "GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY   '#{slave_password_data_bag_item['password']}'"
  action :query
end
```

You'll need this cookbook https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/database. It is possible to have differences in resource's attributes because this examples are not from latest version.

> How would you set different privileges and passwords based on
>   different environments

For this you can use env options in chef and/or combine them with chef roles.

To have one resource executed specifically per environment you can use `not_if` or `only_if` attributes applied to resource:

```
mysql_database_user 'app-user' do
  not_if { node.environment == 'devel' }
end
```

and using helpers with it:

```
ENV_DEV ||= 'dev'

def dev_env?
        node.environment == ENV_DEV
end

mysql_database_user 'app-user' do
  not_if { dev_env? }
end
```

You can combine this with env_roles and have specific roles for your environment. Those roles will include recipes that will manage your credentials. In that way you will ave not_if and if options.

More about env and roles - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-environments-in-chef-to-control-server-configurations

> Would you use data bags or is there any other way to manage these?

Yes I would use that with proper abstraction in libraries to minimize duplicate code to call something out from databag.

There is a way to hide decrypted output in chef log, in that way your log will not contain sensitive info.

> We have a Chef repo for dev and a separate repo for prod.

To me is ok to start with one chef cookbook with recipes, roles, env e.g. one codebase to manage all your nodes.

You can expand this incrementally when your requirements got up to base cookbook and higher cookbooks that will use base cookbook as dependency. In that way you will overcome big cookbooks with lots of recipes and libraries.

Comment: The database cookbook has been deprecated. Chef states they'd like to have each provider cookbook (e.g. mysql) handle these themselves instead, but it doesn't appear that's actually taken place. Not a good look for the Chef team, especially for companies who would rather not have a package or cookbook they depend on be deprecated in favor of, apparently, nothing.

Comment: Defining a database and a user assigned to it as resources was exactly what I thought the official mysql cookbook would let me do. Then after figuring out how to get it installed, and testing that it was installed and running properly I realize it doesn't do that for me. Really disappointing. I think the best thing to do is define the resource myself, revert to installing the package myself, and maybe make a PR for the official cookbook with my resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically boils down to "write the code you want to write". Do you like data bags and have a good workflow for managing them? Then cool, use those. Want to store stuff in recipe code? That's cool too. I would recommend against using attributes but if it works for you then sure, for got it.

Personally I would do it in recipe code because it should be versioned alongside everything else in the recipe.

Comment: How to avoid exposing passwords in recipe code? data bags on the other hand can be encrypted

Comment: My citadel cookbook is an option if you're on AWS, otherwise chef-vault is not the worst but is not wonderful, Hashicorp Vault is probably the best available system currently but takes some work to set up and integrate. See https://coderanger.net/talks/secrets/ for 30m of me talking about this.